# Lambda function issue with "gpg returned a non-zero error code"

Tags: python, aws-lambda, gnupg

I'm facing an issue trying to encrypt file with gnupg in AWS lambda.
the error I got:

```
gpg returned a non-zero error code: 2
```

so I have an ECR image for the lambda function that contains the binary for gnupg and I can trigger the lambda with an event from a S3 bucket so that the lambda will encrypt that file and drop into another S3 bucket folder.

for the public key, I'm storing the string file in secret manager as below format:

```
    -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

mQGNBGUowL8BDADUvYGdRKKn4j4ORdZ8q6GDtAJ3rVi0dxoM9HzY4MVtSB4NeFGr
/s+1BlqCnOV3p7Eg/jVf/PfAcr49P0g9rBlqMTbhBPG8ter+m3FrtvJ0iPcfhERD
umTWmWO1WFE4d+NhTQY8MXC7Jv2170/kU7TRZ9SkxSzvv/lktoqsiGZ3G91y2Hom
8iHWzVwGiM/BMjH33SPaCZNG885URYPSw8CJliC4HesTU0L/Zs0f/kLVOhj3Q8oz
EsyPapRJdMZil7QM1FtiXVqyJM9Cq4z2x0GbyUcxUkzhBBsEYzmuVgVsm1ksyqEN
ZkaXxonhV4cSFJDBJ+ffpZQR7QlpAsh8JNRYsuSD2nCADE//zreLHPr7mRKHbnk/
5GMNyL/Xvj0feQfj/KSpyd3nqFPLzbTts88I4HKb8YzoJ3efwnZTcV41rffy+Sca
cYngMEConQ4DiWqoIASmVEdi0SWzWqKx37g9YgzB3GzETtWLEZxzXOtOUzlfPGlw
LThgYpP9Vq+6cQUAEQEAAbQeYW5keSBwaGFtIDxhbmR5cGhhbUBnbWFpbC5jb20+
iQHUBBMBCgA+FiEE1DZISCCJ3amO+qOU30T6iI8+tN8FAmUowL8CGwMFCQPCZwAF
CwkIBwIGFQoJCAsCBBYCAwECHgECF4AACgkQ30T6iI8+tN9kSwwAtpXPZIL8CUic
lODyq4e0LSo7eMOg9gadCKpJFgzDNtQdqD0Z1Dyz7jIYaYI8ZXk2b73G6onsLZPD
KA710JBE6lXPvM4Zyjv2ewwVn2kFtyi2RRD/3AQASl3C3NEarOTEYUSRxfBz85WD
5ssj3Zlzz1KEyYdA8HF/AmL/iLX+90HH/mTWjTI0gYULmYHK+dNJ5mC54J+z1EZ3
EQHLbk3AgXoEfJTTtNIobtIG4FvisWN+6L734vU/inpeyvAExZ4vschTuGY4xe7b
qgbgqfajwzckitGMeV1KGNvaCmpMb8L3qE7JPPoLHFNtV8BofMn1sM82woG3TDCS
uHxlxn5wwFrzmvnJ7y1D7DHqCW9FchFjfV2alkX4yttN1QVTpeXBIgSu5hlbmGLm
ZmsRg2itQACjrNqLwRObtHxY8qc3K9tMg0UVSDcGWFxSvrPzHMmDWufCIEd1ZYbC
jtKIa1mT9IjrET+i5EiWq3Jp4duWAEnLuCsgj35wyE8LDf6H7mOPuQGNBGUowL8B
DAC4jwLpS3lLt8XJT9dTAKTgujDGQNeAL58ikE2x9qi32eGqEHcjYMeODxcgsfab
iF1JDhPo5t94eIvmzk6D2FB6Jtiop3vJI2EQwW0IzzsSDqrOJ+nX0Z143DO9zRAb
aRLbI9k65KJFKb5JUoF0JJhSTx/+eSaZZ8mxXILv8aIMsFd8ByfhIRVmXqAL/vJn
+1NhOSueN6MHr6V9JcXIv6KpRyHlehMGUAU//K1nbJPvElPj2pjUxGo6vtGfMloc
uSQk1VXe/DhivI5ywcxZx+rl07Qs8eD1VZc2skFNpeu/34sYvvhYUEp/TyGWmYR2
L+p/3yjHd10R/XtolNRB20jB7UVf167B2PLh+1pjKAFoF0wYJGzpFpVhjkoOsrZ2
2W57W42ox7II2Ww7rPxWYTA7rzeo+M3kenjo+L60SuB6IxO8YI94xMu2DN+dSnBS
8QkCgovmx4TzEWKQl3MpFTehUNNtx31xHnBpY/rZJjEDt4RXXb6X6QwZ7UbOCuyE
VA8AEQEAAYkBvAQYAQoAJhYhBNQ2SEggid2pjvqjlN9E+oiPPrTfBQJlKMC/AhsM
BQkDwmcAAAoJEN9E+oiPPrTfgUAMAJWtbtKYd3TgwozOilvaKKFD9Cz4SsHX+tq8
TaLMlKcP1Z17UpOG6szWKmwf8OgccIngmwsJwmwpnvg4lL+yQFLHTuTNrUHPLGqr
NEzajMtyMgcfkCpcC0CaEss7vIh78yB4d+EioNGnjOyQSMw/X4kIKws6qWAOETtf
8FoJHXPwBd8Gg3PgZpNAp2qWcdX2bECjWhqquJaPirL1Z+YKIzZPFGzh0o7CUVwZ
rD0cHuFbXYIRu5dP5n2iec6F+55AHwCuUxaKanyINauP7x+Nf5stqvfZjPaTirZU
jf9jhkgWVBxIfeMyAmT7kXXZqyXFavjFHsf/I4sTBmIn+HlWIg9zh+d9yQRX8M2u
1avceP0xjqlw9LHQ6BNaSddpBAFxjF5yK5iaHQTsUGpddh4RFCtxiPZGl+PPRdnl
Cxra/rG86JbKPNvDusKFsnuquTCO2zLZOTx3w42j5MwUi6MaGC1hJpkW8fNO+pEU
RDe7g1DRBHPCYodIhcVBIhCxDGg2aZkBjQRlKWPpAQwAmqpu4T5BCifY9rQgLjic
NlpNdns7xRtEXmDQVKzyLi4c1inTJrZLI0LpvZBSjN+/EmNQT1wDEcV6fwtqMVeE
90RzjrNpQsA4bmbpOCd7RDBeSL7C679YsL9CZu/RPR0TsOpZyRkSQr8NiKZ0k1XR
VnIe/0uUhCnkhqy4ro2qtf5Mwo2mA49bnA5RhCwTsYvx4KyCACyKdj+7X0cBf00A
0QmE+qPRty7P+8BhbzrVer+jiNPRdg2RurxFHXOFQ67T+GICosxlfz/lPZENPb6S
2i0NNysaNxh+Iol3NeU+yFJZCu16D1L8L94mi9kX8fCKD/Ed1JjX1taPZV+MAlGO
CSWxS7YOLk8lo9HC6qdbIkXBz7Ch7Xzi1FSV8w0O+GuNwNmnmmF7R7mKDts5Fd1r
1vbOqsqNuGNctJW9TnL4zDnxsLiZU7m5LgRUJRvVkqVtG/Yv6gCEfm185BzDyjnn
Cdzb5iQOl1pC00j61oWFWZtLT0QHnGhLuASGHBcDqQWnABEBAAG0HWFuZHlwaGFt
IDxhbmR5cGhhbUBnbWFpbC5jb20+iQHUBBMBCgA+FiEEiU7hrk7ezt9S98gmJU+e
kw5tGsgFAmUpY+kCGwMFCQPCZwAFCwkIBwIGFQoJCAsCBBYCAwECHgECF4AACgkQ
JU+ekw5tGsigfwv+MgG+0IsY9oeEDZKYIONrRIOvLaW+AySleE7sgp/V3m9dYeUm
tE0RTxlifp8xHctxbmEEsfSmrFNCwqQOK7VhXP7UPTC09XRAWGV2tc3z8gxXY7ZD
LyE3f+zabqazo+PKUOKRR1lGARX/n5fyF3yZcr21c+ZbO07DBSqeoa/02e0aNUZc
eFxiHji1sGLpQRqhnq/h11cr47DNDGpFwISAgvs61Hm+EWtd+/+t/GzjVfM2+/eS
wTtsxZtJ1pP4Rrni6RNnG9uqUGBVoghMs1SqxaE9JqKQy19+NUop9ZpSWewzX6J6
hlVNFcz/ttEJ0Mx940Hk5QhGBh0/1pPamLkfqxQ5z17QpqI7mDJtqxKkV+guMRbR
Gs898rf8hJB4iIQc/5SvUaXJvac3sj1rMuk259SY3IoUjxva5dLgcOmhV2Mkf8jn
erhGZninvsGIK7VRJKsAQrffxF2WaWHtbCN/4wsCqq8V3rPHHeoLbZExGqzraDef
wp/Cz2n/a+9iAgP+uQGNBGUpY+kBDADoowDn+dYdhx9tElKHXiZXiCLGZ1Sb+y+U
32OgcX+4QDNUPb3ncvz0ExOHa9mIc/DN1PcmwKlAqaQw3oI+mBU9biJQHFuHGdpJ
N4G0Ybm/4kmoV/77FcBEHL6Xwtcowu+TK/Fvfp+ppeYHjP0BzYlz3tEpWHOZWWDY
P/+DuHO6bQkTbb8z2F2O4g+Bwuy8WmRFs5djUKWjq0T8DAIvl+QZgBYoIq3qtDen
PupH2/d6ohE0qG8KkdKpILpCQJ9HjFxFoTNvYZiOLtAP2yLCuBChoMxCc5z4g/M1
M/Ts5W5ydct0DOc0oscYT7BccK5JTTXQq8tvkNYJk6mBl/KVhjDzve2KDyLqHUOM
YJAyXeEb4INtuaqAEB8GSbmpzW87MyCYKIguuCQcWEHLZz745VD7LExjGailOFor
q7cy/SQcTmfhpQ1nPqX3XXfCJN+Kge10pX0qcVwt6+x06buiRT0jw1qGy1dyGlTL
uxd4feyzRdEJnRSzccAaef6BhUg/kksAEQEAAYkBvAQYAQoAJhYhBIlO4a5O3s7f
UvfIJiVPnpMObRrIBQJlKWPpAhsMBQkDwmcAAAoJECVPnpMObRrIln0L/RoQOFXW
qLWRNLy6KpBDv0HhmXN385ibtk4nIJv8rGpVjj2RlWrINMI2V3w2UUVdHCmFwA2+
VRW+XVRhjq+Rch9G2i0gNAWo+UVubD+NcFMMkVICS/88XFY4KyHzyVjfAnYbkwAj
WAlPLYeSM3+33wbd0/EBdRXO+qGrpwItj3Jo9RWK/hBZlZy1jhTfLGqkkCTtx5io
ecd4vIZsWSuh2AUtLb+TLiMlM9fX9Aag/xFWk0cnB5y0YThbzef5ZWtw6L8+9OSL
BoXwu6jxA8ynVYHRcLMt2O22/XaCC0eddjEl6PYkCdhYcLgDjfu2g1W9E3dDvY8G
OeZ8LYoXeFc5erqyXJ9O5LGxXrZY2AUvpXMGwIREg3IWrw3BZzbsg9SrnT94b+aa
n+YJXmiegCgGUb4Ds0BL/ShNsdLvKXlpp/SeGym3oIwSrN/w90ZPfzptWZtiWHER
WU0pS09T+dFxBv5JIG4yLorGXABuRvwYjMq2eB4OOwiPYEkQ+ACjQ8g1zQ==
=8h+y
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

I'm thinking when I copied and pasted above string into the secret manager value section, it will change the format so that gpnup couldn't process it properly.

I also tried to use `\n` into the key as the line break but it still doesn't work.

the import key code is:

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/tmp', gpgbinary='/usr/bin/gpg')
public_key_secret = fetch_secret(PUBLIC_KEY_SECRET_NAME)
public_key_str = private_key_secret["public_key_file"]
gpg.import_keys(public_key_str)
```

the encryption code is:

```
with open(temp_path, "rb") as f:
        encrypted_path = f'/tmp/{encrypted_name}'
        encrypted_data = gpg.encrypt_file(f, 'xxxx@gmail.com', always_trust = True, output=encrypted_path)
```

if anyone has the same experience with solution, please help to advise me.
many thanks

Comment: @ryley I checked that link before but their approach is not my solution unfortunately

Comment: Alright, I'm sorry for implying that you didn't do enough prior research.